# Frame differencing

Tags: opencv, frame, tracking, surf

I am trying to detect motion for the purpose of object tracking using frame differencing, but my camera is a moving one mounted on UAV.

So I am trying to return the case to static camera scenario through frame alignment so subtracting is done only on overlapped area.

The methods I found use SURF to do the alignment,  but my goal is to reduce the process power needed. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Lucas-Kanade tracker (see [this function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk)) applied on FAST keypoints (see [this function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html?#fast)).

The FAST keypoint detector is a very efficient way to detect corners in an image and the KLT is a very efficient algorithm to track salient points in a video. Combining these two functions is a known technique to efficiently get point matches between two frames of a video.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to use FAST for matching but not with KLT, do you have any example doing this?